# How to modify title of all bar charts in a spreadsheet using google-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a file named `testscript.csv` which has `Sheet1` as my current active sheet. It has a total of 48 bar charts which do not have a `left-axis title` and I want to convert all of the titles to be `Response Time (ms)`.

Is it possible to do this using a google-script?

I was going through the documentation. I tried the following exa

```
function modifyAllCharts() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  for (var chart in charts) {
    chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('title', 'Updated!')
    .build();
    sheet.updateChart(chart);
  }
}
```

but I am getting error at `getCharts()`

```
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 3, file "Code")
```

How to make this work? I am using this for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCharts()` returns an array of EmbeddedCharts.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcharts

You need to reference the EmbeddedChart as an array element not an object.

```
function modifyAllCharts() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();

  for (var i in charts) {
    var chart = charts[i].modify()
    .setOption('title', 'Updated!')
    .build();
    sheet.updateChart(chart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I tried this but I still am getting the same error on line 3. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PJGG985ACw1isKGg1Q6-JhWge9uhQJdgXZCDZ_3T5Ac/edit#gid=0) is the sheet I am trying to use with the code given.

Comment: Your chart had had an improper range. The chart itself was throwing the error. Once I fixed the range the code I posted above works as intended.

Comment: I do see that my chart was different but what exactly is meant by chart having an improper range?

Comment: It looked like the A1 notation was wrong for the range. It was confusing the chart service.